# Why won't my button grab the second item within the array after it grabs the first?

Tags: jquery

When the button is clicked, it gets an "a" from the '/tutorial.html' page, stores it in an array, and then appends it to the element with the class ".more" (current page). It does this with the code provided.

However, when I click the button again, nothing happens. I want the button to grab the next element in the array when I click it a second time.

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var morePosts = [];

  function getMore() {

    var x = 0;
    var nextPost = morePosts[x];

    $(".more").append(nextPost);

    x++;

  }

  $(".loadMoreButton").on("click", function() {

    if (morePosts.length == 0) {

      $.get('/tutorials.html', function(data) {

        $(data).find('#main li a').each(function() {
          morePosts.push(this);
          getMore();
        });

      });

    }

    else if (morePosts.length > 0) {

      getMore();

    }


  });

});
```

Comment: Everytime you run this `var nextPost = morePosts[x];` x will always be 0, move `var x = 0;` out of `getMore()`

Comment: Hmm, did that and now it's grabbing all of the items within the array. Do I need to convert the "<a>" within the array to a string first before appending it?